# How can i pull data from up to 60 days if the oldest is more than 60 days old, if not then up to that date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

How can i pull data from up to 60 days if the oldest is more than 60 days old, if not then up to that date

```
SELECT itemName, category, store
From storeItems 
WHERE itemDate <= CASE  
WHEN MIN(itemDate) >= DATEADD(d,-60,GETDATE())
THEN DATEADD(d,-60,GETDATE()) ELSE MIN(itemDate) 
END
```

Comment: Your question is like the davinci code... please explain further with examples

Answer (score 1):

> pull data from up to 60 days if the oldest is more than 60 days old, if not then up to that date

The question and the code make it really look like you just want:

```
where itemDate >= DATEADD(d, -60, GETDATE())
```

If the earlierst `itemDate` is less than 60 days away, this returns all the rows. If it is older than 60 days, you just get the rows for the last 60 days.